# PHPExcel how to solve the encoding issue when reading a file

Tags: php, yii2, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I was working on an Yii2 API where i need to upload a .csv or .xlsx file and read from it using PHPExcel(DEPRECATED now , but  i am stuck with it as new one PhpSpreadsheet requires PHP version 5.6 or newer) and return the array of data .

This was the code used in the API function

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $params = $_FILES['uploadFile'];
    if($params)
    {
        $data = array();
        $model = new UploadForm();
        $model->uploadFile = $_FILES['uploadFile'];
        $file =  UploadedFile::getInstanceByname('uploadFile');
        $inputFileName = $model->getpath($file,$data);
        //  Read your Excel workbook
        try
        {
            $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName['link']);
            $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            if($inputFileType == 'CSV')
            {   


                if (mb_check_encoding(file_get_contents($inputFileName['link']), 'UTF-8'))
                {
                    $objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-8');
                }
                else
                {
                     $objReader->setInputEncoding('Windows-1255');
                     //$objReader->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-8');
                }


            }
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName['link']);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName['link'],PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
        }

        //  Get worksheet dimensions
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
        $fileData = array();
        //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
        { 
            //  Read a row of data into an array
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                            NULL,
                                            TRUE,
                                            FALSE);
            array_push($fileData,$rowData[0]);
            //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here
        }
        return $fileData;
    }

}
```

But there are encoding issues when we upload a excel file  containing hebrew data  in it .  As you can see the code below  from the above code was used to  address this issue

```
if (mb_check_encoding(file_get_contents($inputFileName['link']), 'UTF-8'))
{
    $objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-8');
}
else
{
        $objReader->setInputEncoding('Windows-1255');

}
```

Later i found that  `UTF-8` and `Windows-1255` are not the only possible encoding  for the flies that may be uploaded but other encoding like `UTF-16` or other ones depending upon the Operating System of  user. Is there any better way to  find the encoding other than using [mb_check_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php)

The common error that occur during the process of  reading the data in file is :

```
iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string
```

As you can see the above error occurs due to the inability to detect the appropriate encoding of the file. Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

You can attempt to use `mb_detect_encoding` to detect the file encoding but I find that results vary. You might have to manually specify a custom match order of encodings to get proper results. Here is an example substitute for the `if` statement in question:

```
if(inputFileType == 'CSV')
{
    // Try to detect file encoding
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($inputFileName['link']),
                     // example of a manual detection order
                    'ASCII,UTF-8,ISO-8859-15');

    $objReader->setInputEncoding($encoding);
}
```

Comment: actually i had  used that method before by using mb_detect_encoding against an array of  encoding types  (as i had to consider  a bunch of encoding types  ) but ,  the problem is  mb_detect_encoding  will not detect  exact encoding  its just guessing  and you may get different result and depends upon the list of encoding you are compare with .  Currently the only possible   working method is to read the file using JavaScript  in the client side  and change the encoding  there before sending it to server . Since i solved it in JavaScript instead of above method i did not post the answer here

Comment: also if anyone is looking for the solution to this problem , this is how i solved it in JavaScript , checkout my other stackoverflow  thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385028/filereader-read-file-using-correct-encoding-when-read-as-readasarraybuffer/

Comment: just an update here:  i could not find a solution at php side, so solved  the encoding problem using JavaScript  . ie  before sending the data to the php .check the link above to see the solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the first clean the output buffer in your page:

```
ob_end_clean();
header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="uploadFile.xls"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks,  but  method  will not work  in this case as its an API  and here i am reading file at the server and sending back the data as json