# how can i use sheetjs to read arabic data from excel file

Tags: javascript

I neet to read excel file that contains Arabic characters but that characters appear not correctly

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script lang="javascript" src="js-xlsx-master/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <span>Red Stapler - SheetJS </span>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <input type="file" id="input-excel"/>

        </div>
        <script>
            $('#input-excel').change(function(e){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
                var fu1 =  document.getElementById("input-excel");
                var name = fu1.value;
                name = name.split("\\").pop();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                    var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array',charset:'utf-8'});
                    var htmlstr = XLSX.write(wb,{charset:'utf-8',type:'binary',bookType:'html',cellDates:true, cellStyles:true});
                    alert(htmlstr);
                    $('#wrapper')[0].innerHTML += htmlstr;
                    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows;
                    alert(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML);
                }

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

expected output : رقم البطاقة
actual output   : Ø±ÙÙ Ø§ÙØ¨Ø·Ø§ÙØ©

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem might be related to how the file data is being loaded, even before it's passed to the SheetJS library. See this post: [Filereader read file using correct encoding when read as readAsArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385028/filereader-read-file-using-correct-encoding-when-read-as-readasarraybuffer)

Comment: the file data is correct the change happen in the stream between file and html page

Answer (score 2):

try adding the `codepage` option to help parse foreign languages such as

`XLSX.read(data, {type: ..., codepage: 28596});`

where 28596 is for ISO 8859-6 Arabic.

Try going through https://github.com/sheetjs/js-codepage to find the codepage ID depending on the language you're parsing.

Comment: have you tried using some other codepage code? Arabic specific ofc.

Comment: alright, if it's encoded in UTF8, make sure that it starts with the UTF8 BOM. If not, then passing the codepage should work.

Comment: make sure that it starts with the UTF8 BOM.how can i do that

Comment: i can't understand python code ,  how can i check that in javascript

Comment: it's best if you Google search. I believe I have pointed you in the right direction based on what problems I've faced before. Python code is nearly pseudo-code shouldn't be too difficult to understand.

Comment: if the ut8-bom is present, specifying the codepage will interpret the first line incorrectly, so then you have to leave the codepage out. otherwise, without bom, you should specify codepage 65001.