# Encoding in uploaded file from angular 6 to .net core api

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm uploading file in UTF-8 but uploaded file on server has ANSI. 
How can I keep the same encoding?

I'm using angular 6 and .net core api.

This is my service in Angular 6

```
postFiles(files) {    
const formData = new FormData();

for (let file of files) {
  formData.append(file.name, file);
}

const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', this.baseUrl, formData, {
  reportProgress: true,      
});
this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
    this.result = event.body 
  }
});}
```

.net core api

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<ApiResult> Import()
    {
        string fullPath = string.Empty;
        try
        {               
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string dir = GetDirectoryPath();
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                fullPath = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
            return new ApiResult();

        }
        return new ApiResult(); 
    }
```

Comment: can you specify what is the format of file that you are uploading ?

Comment: It's .csv file. Content-Type of request is multipart/form-data.

Comment: For upload file I'm using HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'

Comment: here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385028/filereader-read-file-using-correct-encoding-when-read-as-readasarraybuffer

Comment: you can use file reader to read the file  using a specific encoding for example `reader.readAsText(f,'ISO-8859-8');`  and then send the data to the server which will solve this issue

Comment: here is the link to `xlsx` package  : https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx to the